# MySQL Storage issue : delete previous day data and insert new records everyday via RDS MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization, amazon-rds

I have questions about reclaiming storage space after performing significant deletes.
The deleted records are not freeing up the storage space. Do we have to perform `optimize table tablename` query everytime to free up the deleted storage space ? Is there any configuration which will help us to free up the storage space?

We are using InnoDB tables

Optimize query : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a case for **`PARTITIONing`**.

- `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))`
- Use a partition key of the datetime of the data;
- Adjust the indexes.
- Set up a script to `DROP PARTITION` and `REORGANIZE PARTITION` every hour.

Note: I suggest hourly partitions so that you have at most 25 hours' worth of data in the table at a time.

More discussion in my blog:  [*Partition*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

**`DELETE`** leaves free space in the table; the free space will be reused by subsequent `INSERTs`.  If you stick with the non-partition approach, I suggest you have a continuously running task that repeatedly does

```
DELETE ... 
    WHERE .. < NOW() - 24 HOUR
    LIMIT 1000`
```

*and* have an index on that key.  More in my blog:  [*Big Deletes*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig)  It also shows a technique if you need to scan the `PRIMARY KEY` instead of having a special index.

**`OPTIMIZE TABLE`** is likely a "bad idea".  It blocks the usage of the table.  The space that it recoups is soon glommed onto.  I  guess that your current technique is oscillating between one and two day's worth of data.

Make sure that **`innodb_file_per_table`** is set to `1` *before* any major activity on the table.  (It is a reasonable default, and it may already be set that way.

My suggestions will keep the disk space used between 1.0 and 1.04 day's worth (24-25 hours).  `PARTITIONing` does not benefit from `OPTIMIZE` unless things get messed up.  Continuous partial deletions may or may not need `OPTIMIZE`; it depends on the details of the table structure.  Would you care to share it?  I may have other tips -- such as using smaller "ints" where appropriate.

Comment: @Fastnlight - I have no affiliation; I am retired.  I wrote the linked documents; they are the result of decade(s) of use of MySQL and MariaDB.

Comment: @Fastnlight - Does the edit I just made satisfy the disclosure requirement?

Comment: Thank you, this will work for us. instead of deleting the data, plan is to have partitioning and drop the partition.